# react-navigation - Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'react-native-safe-area-view'

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to figure out, why `react-native-safe-area-view` from `react-navigation` is not able to find the `react-native` module even though it is installed. The error I'm receiving is below. Could you please help me?

```
./node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view/index.web.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in '........./client/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view'
```

Comment: Try import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation'